# Symfony3 FOSRest cgetAction route not found

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

The project is based on Symfony 3.1 + FOSRest 2.0.

I have a controller with following methods:

```
...
public function cgetCategoryAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAll();

    if (!$entity) {
        return [];
    }

    return $entity;
}

public function getCategoryAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The resource \'%s\' was not found.', $id));
    }

    return $entity;
}
...
```

`GET /api/categories/1` delivers the result, but `GET /api/categories` leads to `405 Route not found`. Adding slash to the end doesn't solve the issue.

According to names convention cgetAction should deliver a collection of entities by `GET /` request. What I'm doing wrong?

### Update

`routing.yml`:

```
app:
    type:     rest
    prefix:   /api
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/api-routing.yml"
NelmioApiDocBundle:
    resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /api/doc
```

`routing-api.yml`:

```
api_Category:
    type: rest
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/CategoryController.php"
    name_prefix:  api_
api_Product:
    type: rest
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/ProductController.php"
name_prefix:  api_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue. looks like the action declared first in the controller gets overwritten by the second. ie. if cgetCategoryAction is declared first, the getCategoryAction replaces it. so if you swap their order, you'll get the opposite problem. Only one of the routes gets generated.

I resolved it through
[implicit resource naming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html#implicit-resource-name-definition)

add the implements ClassResourceInterface, and remove the 'Category' from the Action names - FOSRestBundle will work that bit out from the Controller name.

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;


class CategoryController extends Controller implements ClassResourceInterface {

    public function cgetAction() {...}

    public function getAction($id) {...}
}
```

and you can check what the automatically generated routes look like from the console with the command:

```
php app/console router:debug
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, in your code:

```
if (!$entity) {
   return [];
}
```

This won't work the way you expect. $entity is a results set. So you need to check the count:

```
if ( count($entity) == 0 ) {
   return [];
}
```

The above checks if it is empty.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check if it is the reason of my problem.

Comment: It's a pity, but the question seems is more oriented on FOSRest bundle automatic routes generation, so I'm expecting an answer why route ```/api/categories``` isn't working. But your comment is correct.

Comment: Hi Anton. You should click on the up arrow for my answer, since it was helpful. Regarding the routes. You probably need to post more information. For example, i don't see any routing annotations, or you haven't shown your routing.yml file or other files that affect routing.

Comment: Thanks, I attached routing-related files. Please let me know if additional information is needed.